# How to refresh a dropdown field in a form without freshing the entire form using ajax?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, yii, dropdownbox

There is a form, whose one of the field is a dropdown field with item names from database.

There is a provision to add new item, by clicking "Add New" button, a pop up will appear and we can save the new item.

Though it is saved in database, it is not reflected in the dropdown field, so we need to refresh.But refreshing the entire page result in loosing the values entered in other fields.

My question is, How to Refresh only this dropdown field without refreshing the entire form?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: which dropdown are you using select2 or a normal dropdown you should add your code

Comment: @Viswa I have completed the entire coding. It is  Yii framework. I had 1st made my code such a way that when a new item is added, the enitre pages is refreshed. Since that was not the correct method i tried using ajax.  Now the only issue is with refreshing dropdown field.

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam, I am using a dropdown with live search option (data-live-search), so there will be a text box along with <option> tags to search in the dropdown list, incase there is no result for the searched word, a link to add new item is shown

Comment: and this would be when using `Select2` dropdown plugin ?

Comment: break-up wall of text

Answer (score 1):

To add a new element to a drop down box in jQuery, use the code below, replacing the element ID, a_value and a_text with the correct information (the input information from the "Add New" button).

```
let dropdown = $('#dropdown');
dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', a_value).text(a_text));
```

Or:

```
$('#dropdown').append($('<option></option>').attr('value', a_value).text(a_name));
```

Comment: I am using a yii dropdown with live search option (data-live-search), so there will be a text box along with <option> tags to search in the dropdown list, incase there is no result for the searched word, a link to add new item is shown

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but with a notification box, so I attached an event to it which starts by clicking on it. This event was sending some information to a PHP file and the PHP file responds with the notifications from the database. You can do the same, When the user clicks on the dropdown field a request will be sent using ajax to the PHP file to get the info from the database and after the user adds the item and saves, if he clikced on the dropdown menu to close it a request will be sent with out the page realod to the database to get the info need. Or you can even attach the event to the button that says "Save" or something, so when he clicks save, the request will be sent and the respond will be appended to the content of teh dropdown menu without reloading.

My code was as following :
JQuery:-

```
// the event click is attached to the icon of the notification through its class 
$('.icon').click(function () {
//I used this line to make the hidden notification box slide down to show content
    $('#notifications-box').slideToggle(400);
//here the ajax request will be sent on the click
    $.ajax({
// The method of sending the data is POST because it is more seucre
        method: "POST",
//the File that you want to the send the data to 
        url: "get_notifications.php",
// The data that needs to be sent
        data: {
            //the name       : // the value 
            get_notifications: "true"
        },
// then on success the return will be appended to the notification box ( status is the respond )
        success: function (status) {
            $('.notifications-box').append(status);
        }
    });
});
```

and then you can use `isset()` in the php file to know if the data was sent to the php file from the ajax request by using

//isset($_method(POST / GET)['the name you sent that was inside the curly brackets of the data object in the ajax request'])

`isset($_POST['get_notifications'])`